# I need help in crystal report with vb.net 2008

Tags: crystal-reports

I had been asked to build crystal reports for an application, i used the Microsoft Report Viewer control from the Tools, and could build a report which get data from datasource according to a parameter and view it in the report viewer, i need to know if i'm doing right or not? is this crystal report? and if not where can i find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Crystal Report Viewer and create Crystal Reports. Microsoft Report Viewer is not the same.